# How to reverse a string using a recursive function?

Tags: java, string, recursion

I've seen lots of posts about reversing a string with recursion, but I like to use my own style of coding to properly understand it. Anyway here is the code I have.

```
private static String reverse (String s){

    String rev = "";
    int index = s.length()-1;
    if(index >= 0){

        rev += s.charAt(index);
        index--;
        rev += reverse(rev);


    }
        return rev;

    }
```

Basically index just keeps going for every single character when index is -1 the loop stops. it reads the last possible character of the string but there is an error in this line here.

```
rev += rev(str)
```

Here is iterative method

```
String dog = "dog";
String rev = "";

int index = dog.length()-1;
while(index >= 0){
    rev+=dog.charAt(index);
    index--;

}

out.println(rev);
```

Comment: Yes I am using java.

Comment: Try adding `System.out.println(index);` before recursing to see if you can see the problem.

Comment: I'm not fully comprehending.. I apologize I'm new to this recursion stuff. Let's say we have a string called "cat" the index starts at 2, then 1 then 0 so it's all printed out it does reach -1, but it wouldn't go through the loop because it is less than 0? so where is the program going wrong?

Comment: I changed it from rev += reverse(rev) to rev += reverse(s) but it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Add it before `rev += rev(str)`  You'll see why.

Answer (score 1):

I believe when the method calls itself you reset the value of the index. Maybe a better approach would be to have an overloaded method where the original call passes in the string to process and then the remaining calls call a method where you pass in both the string you are building along with the remaining part of the that is being processed.

Comment: I know but it adds the letter before decrementing then when it goes back up the loop is skipped and it should return rev? right?

Answer (score 0):

The recursive step doesn't contain the mutated string. You need to pass the substring of the original string.
`rev = reverse(s.substring(0,index));`

Comment: Ok this fixed it I just indexed too late it makes sense now thank you.

Answer (score -1):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the OP)*.

It's fixed now. Thank you so much, I was indexing too late and passing in negative numbers.

```
private static String reverse (String s) {

int index = s.length();
index--;
String rev = "";
if(index >= 0){
    rev += s.charAt(index);

    rev = rev + reverse(s.substring(0,index));
}

return rev;

}
```